# C++ issue with function pointer as parameter

Tags: c++, function, pointers

I am trying to apply newtons method in C++ and right now just testing out if my pointers work and are correct. Now the issue is it cannot call the function to test this, it says there is an issue with converting.

My code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

double newton(double (*f) (double), double (*fPrime)(double), double intialValue, int    iterations);
double f(double x);
double fPrime(double x);

int main() {


int limitIterations = 0;
double intialValue = 0;


cout << "Please enter a starting value for F(X): " ;
cin >> intialValue;

cout << endl << "Please enter the limit of iterations performed: " ;
 cin >> limitIterations;



cout << newton(intialValue, limitIterations);


return 0;
}

 double f(double x) {
 double y;
 y =(x*x*x)+(x*x)+(x);
 return (y);
 }

double fPrime(double x){
double y;
y = 3*(x*x) + 2 * x + 1;
return (y);

}

double newton(double (*f) (double), double (*fPrime)(double), double intialValue, int     iterations){

    double approxValue = 0;

    approxValue = f(intialValue);

    return (approxValue);

 }
```

And the error:

```
|26|error: cannot convert 'double' to 'double (*)(double)' for argument '1' to 'double  newton(double (*)(double), double (*)(double), double, int)'|
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do want to declare `newton` to take function pointers, then you will need to pass them in at the call-site to `newton`:

```
cout << newton(f, fPrime, initialValue, iterations);
```

The error from the compiler is simply saying that you passed a `double` in a slot where it was expecting a function pointer and that it has no clue how to convert a `double` into a function pointer `double (*)(double)`.

Comment: Thank you! That was the fix I needed! Got my code working and now its time to find zero hahah

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to pass function pointers.  The functions that you defined above can be used directly.  Just define your `newton` function like this:

```
double newton(double intialValue, int iterations) {
    double approxValue = 0;
    approxValue = f(intialValue);
    return (approxValue);
}
```

Comment: Yes, but eventually Im going to approximate 0 of a function using its prime, so i need to pass a function within a function while getting closer and closer to zero. I know this works, but I need to use pointers :)